# PC wont install from pendrive

Tags: installation, usb, drive

I made a bootable usb stick using Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer, but my PC doesn't recognize it when booting.

I have set the BIOS to select USB as first choice but it just bypasses it and boots from the hard disk.

Comment: Try unetbootin to make usb bootable

Answer (score 1):

Download this software [UnetBootIN |Download the windows version if you plan to run the software on windows](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Restart the Live USB drives making process from scratch.

I think something went wrong when the first time you tried. It should work fine this time :)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I'm certain it's not the pendrive as I've previously used this one to successfully update other Linux type boxes (with different software).

Comment: have You tried pressing [ F9 / F2 / F1 ] at the time of boot..
One of them is supposed to give you a list of available boot drive options.. Like Pendrive , USB , CD/DVD.

Comment: Yes thanks, I've tried that. I'm trying to install it on a HP ELite 8100 which I understand uses UEFI.